# Altova Mapforce - checking input XML values including empty/Null and replacing with default value.

Tags: xml, xslt

Altova Mapforce - checking input XML values including empty/Null and replacing with default values.  Not able in XLST to check a element value and replace with a replacement vlaue if required.

For example the sending XML should contain a date as 00000000 and if that is the case, I need to substring the first 8 characters of another data element that is a date+time, that's the reason for the substring.

Then if the element is blank/empty/null I need to replace with a value to ensure the next process step will not fail due to missing key data.

Cheers

Comment: Can you please show your current input XML, and the output you expect in this case. Also, can you show the XSLT you have currently tried, if possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: No able to upload as text it's too long, not sure what to do?

Comment: How do I check for an for example <Name></Name> is blank, null, empty in MapForce and then put a value if empty?

Comment: You don't need to show your entire XML, just enough to demonstrate the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Thanks!